# why i cant see smoke effect?

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, fire

I  am beginner to the blender,  have just 1-month experience I never tried any simulation but now I tried smoke effect but I can't get any smoke I have seen youtube tutorials, I followed the same but no difference, I can't get the smoke and fire.[image]